# Is there any way to store a 2D array in a persistant storage?

Tags: android, arrays, persistence

I want to load a 2D array like this one:

```
[
  [false, true, false, false],
  [true, false, false, false],
  [false, false, false, true],
  [false, false, true, false],
  [false, false, true, false]
]
```

Actually, these are the radio button states, false indicating radiobutton is uncheck while true indicating that the radio button is checked.

To explain the whole scenario, I am creating a quiz, which has a question and options for this i have created a `radiobuttonStates[][]` 2D array. The first [] indicating number of questions versus number of options in second []. There is a save and exit button which saves the quiz (saving the question number from where the user left and the selected radio buttons, previous as well as present). So the 2D array which i have created in the first attempt of the quiz, I want to load this same array when the user again comes back and resumes the quiz. Right now i am thinking to store this array in some persistant storage (Database or any kind). But I am not getting any way on how to store. The user clicks the resume button and I am showing the current question number from the database but not able to show the radio button selection. Please help me.

Comment: There are several ways: If it's a set of a small number of buttons then you could store them in SharedPreferences, naming each entry like "Button1-2" or so. If the number is higher you could either write the data as XML/JSON/Serializable/.. to disk or you can use a SQLiteDatabase

Answer (score 1):

Well you can always transform your boolean array into a string(or more strings), and store it in `SharedPreferences`.

For example: ResultString = "false,true,false,false";

When you need the result back from the `SharedPreference` just split your strings, using a certain separator (for instance ",") and reuse your saved data.

Like this you get faster store/restore data backup. Using SQLite to store this kind of data is not a good idea.

Good luck,
Arkde

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make some kind of table structure where you put each individual array value in a specific row/column. However, if your array contains a small number of elements (like the one you showcase in your question), you can just serialize the instances and save the bytes in the database. This way you won't have to make all the boiler-plate code that thakes each array value and puts it in some row/column and then builds an array out of various row/column values.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and instant way is to store the array or multiple 2d arrays is to use file to read and write your array object.

here is the code sample below which reds my custom objects from a file and writes them to the file. the only thing in the methods below are when reading it reds all objects and when writing it writes all objects  again means you can not append single object with previous file or read single object from file. so if you hae to append another array you have to read all previous ones and then write them again with the increment of one you want to append.

```
    public static boolean writeBlockedMessagesInFile(Context context,
            ArrayList<BlockedMessages> blockedMessages) {
        boolean status = false;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = context.openFileOutput("BlockedMessagesFile.dat",
                    Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            if (blockedMessages != null && blockedMessages.size() != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < blockedMessages.size(); i++)
                    oos.writeObject(blockedMessages.get(i));
            }
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
            status = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }


    public static ArrayList<BlockedMessages> readBlockedMessagesFromFile(Context context) {
        ArrayList<BlockedMessages> blockedMessages = new ArrayList<BlockedMessages>();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        Object object = null;
        try {
            fis = context.openFileInput("BlockedMessagesFile.dat");
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            BlockedMessages blo;
            Object temp;
            try {
                while ((blo = (BlockedMessages) ois.readObject()) != null) {
                    blockedMessages.add(blo);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                npe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (EOFException eof) {
                eof.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                fnfe.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ois != null) {
                    ois.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return blockedMessages;
    }
```